# Will indexing be useful when Inner join is performed between normal table and a select from indexed table

Tags: mysql, indexing, inner-join, query-performance

Suppose I have small table(t1) and large table(t2).I have indexed column1 and column2 of t2. If I want to **INNER JOIN t1 and (select * from t2 where column1=x)**  then is the indexing on t2 be helpful even after the (select * from t2 where column1=x) during the inner join with t1?

If My query is (select * from t2 where column1=x) then obviously indexing is helpful. What happens when my complete query is run? will it first run (select * from t2 where column1=x)(here indexing will be used) and then INNER JOIN with t1 without using indexing?

Comment: Have you used `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see whether the index is being used? But, theoretically, yes, it should be used if the index is on the column you are using as a filter.

Comment: Indexing is often helpful. That's why the MySQL team has spent thousands of developer years making it work well. Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please pay close attention to the section on query performance. Please [edit] your question to provide more details. Please do so promptly to avoid having your question closed "unclear." Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost always it is better to `JOIN` two tables instead of `JOINing` to a "derived" table.

Probably inefficient:

```
 FROM t1
 JOIN ( SELECT ... FROM t2 ... ) AS t3 ON ...
```

Probably better:

```
 FROM t1
 JOIN t2 ON ...
```

One likely exception is when the derived table (`t3`) is much smaller than the table (`t2`) it comes from.  This may happen when there is a `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT`, and/or `LIMIT` inside `t3`.

If you want to discuss further, please provide the fully spelled out `SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables.  An important discussion point is what indexes exist (or are missing).

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need.